# Update JavaFX control from thread started by a library

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, undertow, undertowjaxrsserver

I have a JavaFX 8 application. It uses kind of observer pattern to react to events:

```
public class EventBus {

    public static final EventBus INSTANCE = new EventBus();

    private final Set<EventListener> listeners;

    private EventBus() {
        listeners = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void register(EventListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void fire(Event event) {
        listeners.forEach(listener -> listener.eventFired(event));
    }
}
```

It worked pretty well so far for all my usecases:

- Interaction with buttons
- Events from external controllers, which I observe with `Platform.runLater()` initiated thread
- etc.

Now I want to start embedded Undertow HTTP server and deploy a JAX-RS endpoint inside. Whenever a request comes in there, I want to fire an event from within that endpoint using the above event bus. So, this is how I start Undertow and deploy my JAX-RS app:

```
UndertowJaxrsServer server = new UndertowJaxrsServer().start();
server.deploy(new MyEndpoint(eventBus));
```

The thing is that `new UndertowJaxrsServer().start()` is asynchronous call and it starts a thread of itself. And then when `MyEndpoint` handles a request and tries to fire an event, it happens from that thread, which was started by Undertow.

So in the event listener, if I try to do any updates on the UI, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = XNIO-1 task-1
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:236)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.clear(VetoableListDecorator.java:294)
    at ui.DialogManager.showDialog(DialogManager.java:109)
```

Finally, my question is is there a way to explicitly tell JavaFX to run a piece of code in the UI thread, even if the call stack comes from another one (to which I do not have control and on which I can't do `Platform.runLater()`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `MyEndpoint` is your class then surround invocation of `fire(Event event)` method with `Platform.runLater()` or change `EventBus` class:

```
public class EventBus {

    public static final EventBus INSTANCE = new EventBus();

    private final Set<EventListener> listeners;

    private EventBus() {
        listeners = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public void register(EventListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void fire(Event event) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            listeners.forEach(listener -> listener.eventFired(event));    
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As an optimization you could also run a check within fire, [Platform.isFXApplicationThread()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#isFxApplicationThread--), and just runLater if not on the FX thread, otherwise execute immediately.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first proposal (surrounding the invocation of `fire(Event event)`) worked perfect!